# PHP post url with no action

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the CodeIgniter framework I have a form action that posts the id of a number of checkboxes to a controller. The controller checks each id to ensure it is valid, and then prints off a pdf document. This works fine.

So, my current method is /items, and I am posting to the /documents method

```
function documents()
  if ($this->input->post() && validate_documents())
  {
    $this->load->library('Print_docs');
    $this->print_docs->execute($this->input->post());
  }
}
```

So, if the docs get printed, then this works fine: the user remains on the /items method and pdf is offered as a download in the browser.

If, however, validate_documents() is false, then I dont want anything to happen - i.e. the user should remain on the /items method. However, what is actually happening is that the user is somehow being redirected to the /documents method - and the browser is blank.

So, why is the user being redirected to the /documents method? And how do I keep the user on the /items method no matter what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form post is a page refresh. When the pdf is generated, the page "refresh" is actually you downloading the pdf - so the browser doesn't take you away from the `/items` method -- it's the same as if you open a link with `target="_blank"`, the page is opened in a new window and the current page is untouched.

You can do 1 of 2 things here:

1. Redirect if there is an error in the `documents` method back to `/items`
2. Submit the form via ajax, so whether there is an error or not, you stay on `/items`

Comment: OK, this is the part that I didn't understand - "the page refresh is actually you downloading the pdf". So that makes sense now. Whilst your option 1 would work (or alternatively I just post to the /items method instead), it would lose the list of checkboxes that have been selected. Accordingly, the best option seems to be ajax...unless I'm missing something else obvious.

Comment: I'd actually recommend both approaches. You can submit via ajax to `/items`. However, you'll also need a non-js approach - so submitting to `/items` would work either way (with or without javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It's being redirected, becuse you told it go there (in ).

The only reason it you don't go to documents method, when the validation is ok, is because of the pdf print. What you can do, is have the code from the documents moved to the "items" method, and set the form's action to "items". That way when the validation fails, the users get "redirected" back to the form, where you should provide feedback on what is wrong (ie. error messages).

The form_validation library page has some examples of what I explained: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Answer (score 0):

```
So, why is the user being redirected to the /documents method?
```

is wrong , because when you're checking validation, it's already in the document method.. So you should basically redirect to items function if validation is false..